# return all rows if date filter is null or " "

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with postgres and add date filter in findALL function. What is want, if i pass null or empty string in date filter it should return all rows.

How it will be?

Here is my findAll function.

```js
call.findAll({
        include: [{
            all: true,
            nested: true
        }],
        order: [
            ['start_date', 'DESC']
        ],
        where: {
            [Op.and]: [{
                start_date: {
                    [Op.gte]: fromDate
                }
            }, {
                end_date: {
                    [Op.lte]: toDate
                }
            }]
        }
    })
```